# How to apply groupname to HTML radio buttons in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

Can anyone please tell about how to apply group name to html (input) radio button controls so that i can select any one of the available radio buttons?

I have input radios in a table. Each row contains two radios as follows. I want to select one from each row. But i am able to select only one radio button amongst all radio buttons present on all rows.

```
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />Option1
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />Option2
```

What change i have to make to select one radio button on each row?

Thanks,
~kaps

Comment: Are you saying both of yours can be selected at the same time?

Comment: Do both radio buttons intentionally have the same value? That might be part of the problem...

Comment: The other radio button gets selected if I click it though we have selected the remaining one.

Comment: What kind of table are the radiobuttons in? Are they inside an ASP.NET control? The answer will depend on this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, radiobuttons in HTML do not have group names. Their HTML "name" attribute *is* the group name.

It is important to verify that each radiobutton has a unique "value" attribute. Otherwise there is no way to tell which of the duplicate values was selected:

```
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton1" />Option1 
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton2" />Option2
```

Answer (score 5):

This example lets you choose only one radio button per table row. You have to give all radio buttons the same Name= to create a mutually exclusive group of them.

```
<form>

<table>
<tr><td>
    <!-- Can choose only one of these two. -->
    <input name="group1" type="radio" value="1a" />Option1 
    <input name="group1" type="radio" value="1b" />Option2 
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <!-- Can choose only one of these two. -->
    <input name="group2" type="radio" value="2a" />Option1 
    <input name="group2" type="radio" value="2b" />Option2 
</td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### GroupName to HTML radio buttons in asp.net

### https://www.javatpoint.com/asp-net-radiobutton

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Male" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="Female" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

### After Rendering from asp.net control tag to html

```html
<form method="post" action="./WebControlsASPX.aspx" id="form1">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <span id="Label1">Gender</span>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input id="RadioButton1" type="radio" name="gender" value="RadioButton1" /><label for="RadioButton1">Male</label>
            <input id="RadioButton2" type="radio" name="gender" value="RadioButton2" /><label for="RadioButton2">Female</label>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```